# pass the boolean value to jsp page from controller using path attribute

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I want to know how to set checkbox value from controller .Please find my code.

**Controller**:

```
......
......
Student student=service.findRecord(studentID) //received record from DAOImpl 
.....
.....
return "EditStudent";
```

**Student.java**

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "student_detail")
 public class Student
 {
 @Id 
 @Column(name = "ID")
 @GeneratedValue
 private int ID;
 @Column(name = "studentID")
 private int studentID;
 @Column(name = "studentDescrip")
 private String studentDescrip;
 @Column(name = "status")
 private boolean status;
 .....
 .....getter setter method
```

**EditStudent.jsp**

```
......
......
<tr class="hide convert">
<th>Status</th>
<td><form:checkbox name="Status" id="Status" 
path="student.Status" class="form-control" />
</td>
</tr>
```

My problem is checkbox status always set true.I am getting status value is false in controller, but it does not set status is false in jsp page. Please correct my code...

Comment: What is your controller?  Are you using JSF, struts, SpringMVC or is it a plain Servlet? (you might be missing some tags to this post)

Comment: Spring MVC and JSP

Comment: Please show how you populate the model in controller.

Comment: i retrieved Student model based on student Id.I wrote logic in DAOIMPL. My problem is on JSP page.In controller, i could get the student model. Please i want to know how to set status boolean value to checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using spring tags, you have to use this

```
In your controller you have to add an object "student" to the ModelAndView

<form:form model="student">
   <td>
       <!-- Here you access to the status attribute, case sensitive.--> 
       <form:checkbox id="Status" path="status" class="form-control" />
   </td>
...
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using simple jsp page, then

```
<tr class="hide convert">
    <th>Status</th>
    <td><form:checkbox name="Status" id="Status" 
    path="<%=student.Status %>" class="form-control" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

*please note: you should write logic that will get `student` object before writing this code.*

Comment: if I give as your suggestion i am getting "student cannot be resolved to a variable"

Comment: turns out OP is using spring mvc